# Why doesn't this php site work (password-hash)

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm trying to do a login-site in php but i couldn't find a mistake.
Althought I didnt get an error, it doesn't work.
The database connection works (I tried it).
So in the HTML I have a form with two input tags and a submit button:

```
    <form action="?login=1" method="post">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" required="" placeholder="Name" border-radius="3px" />
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password" border-radius="3px" font-size="caption" />
            <input text-align="center" type="submit" value="Login »"  class="btn btn-white-outline display-4" style="border-radius: 3px !important;">
    </form>
```

And this is the php-code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test_db', 'user', 'password');

if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :username");
    $result = $statement->execute(array('username' => $username));
    $user = $statement->fetch();

    if ($user !== false && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $user['name'];

        die('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/plan.php">');
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "<p style='color:red;'>
        Incorrect username or password.
        </p><br>";
    }

}
?>
```

Can you help me. 
Thank you

Comment: `What` doesn't work?

Comment: The if statment looks for a `$_GET` while you `$_POST` the form

Comment: @SuperDJ The `action` handles that.

Comment: Where does the execution stop?

Comment: Maybe you can try and force PHP to show an error with: `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );` Set this at the top of the file

Comment: @KhorneHoly the submit button is disabled/doesn't work (no-drop  pointer). If I click it. If I try to replace it, the $errorMessage is coming (Incorrect username or password.)

Comment: @SuperDJ I didn't get an error.

Comment: And @chris85 I can't debug the site because it's on the domain server and the Editor doesn't support Debugging (Brackets).

Comment: Try first without the function password_verify(). Then you know if the problem is in this function or above.

Comment: @RemcoK. without the function password_verify() it works. So i come to the plan.php

Comment: Ok. then show the function password_verify() in your question

Comment: @RemcoK. do you mean this?: ($user !== false && password_verify($password, $user['password']))

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct? The function password_verify() expects the second param to be a hash. So the encrypted password created with the function password_hash().

Comment: @RemcoK. thank you very much I didn't stored the password as a hash in the db

Comment: always remember, if you don't get a syntax error, its always your logic's that wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function:

```
password_verify()
```

expects the second param to be a hash of the password created by the function:

```
password_hash()
```

Or store the password as hash in your db.